# Generating Positive Kinetic Energy (PKE) from car velocity

Tags: python, data-science, data-extraction

I have a data frame with 3 columns, Time (each second), Dpeed(KM/H) in each second, from this data frame I want to calculate positive kinetic energy.
This formula i found in this research :

> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235721432_Quality_assurance_of_exhaust_emissions_test_data

PKE = pow(Vf,2) - pow(Vi,2) / distance
I'm new to python and I'm wondering how to implement it.
any help will be appreciated .
what i have tried :

this to calculate the time in hour

```
start=df['Time'].iloc[0]

end=df['Time'].iloc[df.shape[0]-1]
diff = end - start
hr = diff.seconds/3600 #to hr
hr
```

and this to calculate distance

```
avgspeed = df['Vehicle Speed Sensor [km/h]'].mean()
dis = avgspeed * hr
dis
```

and this to calculate pke :

```
z = 0
df['pke'] = 0
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    z = pow(df['Vehicle Speed Sensor [km/h]'].loc[i],2) - pow(df['Vehicle Speed Sensor [km/h]'].loc[i-1],2)
    pke = z / dis
    df['pke'].loc[i] = pke
```

this is the data how its presented
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcY8z.png)

Comment: Can you tell us what did you try ? Any code that u did ?

Comment: We need a lot more information about the problem, anything I suggest would just be a guess. We need to know more about the shape of your data, what outcome you are looking for and what you tried like @RishabhHardas said.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Okay, and what's the problem with this code? I assume it isn't doing what you want to do. Taking a guess, you should look at Pandas apply function and how it can be used to do math on rows to create a new column with a value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do calculations over Excel then compare code output to Excel output to assure your results.